# How to retrieve a value from row of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup

I have a list of values in row in sheet1 (say A1:K1), from this row of data list, I want to search for a value in N1 in sheet2, and if it is present in the row, then put the value in N5. (if the vaue is not there, then N5 should return "Empty").

I tried to use lookup and index function to do that. but I couldn't achieve what I wanted to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Sheet2* cell **N5** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A1:K1,MATCH(N1,Sheet1!A1:K1,0)),"Empty")
```

[image]

where *Sheet1* might contain:

[image]